# Tensorflow Dataset is 3 Times Slower Than the Queue Pipeline?

Tags: python, tensorflow-datasets

I have suffered for the speed of tensorflow dataset api. I test the speed of the dataset pipline and the queue pipline with this code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import glob
import time

import tensorflow as tf


def disk_image_batch_dataset(img_paths, batch_size, shuffle=True, buffer_batch=128, repeat=-1):

    def parse_func(path):
        img = tf.read_file(path)
        img = tf.image.decode_png(img)
        return img

    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(img_paths).map(parse_func)

    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)

    if shuffle:
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_batch)
    else:
        dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_batch)

    dataset = dataset.repeat(repeat)

    # make iterator
    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()

    return iterator.get_next()


def disk_image_batch_queue(img_paths, batch_size, shuffle=True, num_threads=4, min_after_dequeue=100):

    _, img = tf.WholeFileReader().read(
        tf.train.string_input_producer(img_paths, shuffle=shuffle, capacity=len(img_paths)))
    img = tf.image.decode_png(img)
    img.set_shape([218, 178, 3])

    # batch datas
    if shuffle:
        capacity = min_after_dequeue + (num_threads + 1) * batch_size
        img_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([img],
                                           batch_size=batch_size,
                                           capacity=capacity,
                                           min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue,
                                           num_threads=num_threads)
    else:
        img_batch = tf.train.batch([img], batch_size=batch_size)

    return img_batch


paths = glob.glob('img_align_celeba/*.jpg')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        batch = disk_image_batch_dataset(paths, 128, shuffle=True, buffer_batch=128, repeat=-1)
        for _ in range(10):
            start = time.time()
            for _ in range(100):
                sess.run(batch)
            elapse = time.time() - start
            print('Dataset Average: %f ms' % (elapse / 100.0 * 1000))

        batch = disk_image_batch_queue(paths, 128, shuffle=True, num_threads=4, min_after_dequeue=100)
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)
        for _ in range(10):
            start = time.time()
            for _ in range(100):
                sess.run(batch)
            elapse = time.time() - start
            print('Queue Average: %f ms' % (elapse / 100.0 * 1000))
        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads)
```

The output is:

Dataset Average: 98.434892 ms

Dataset Average: 38.566129 ms

Dataset Average: 39.068711 ms

Dataset Average: 39.103138 ms

Dataset Average: 39.217770 ms

Dataset Average: 39.106920 ms

Dataset Average: 38.595331 ms

Dataset Average: 38.467741 ms

Dataset Average: 40.517910 ms

Dataset Average: 40.987079 ms

Queue Average: 44.756029 ms

Queue Average: 14.821191 ms

Queue Average: 14.946148 ms

Queue Average: 14.817519 ms

Queue Average: 14.691849 ms

Queue Average: 15.771849 ms

Queue Average: 16.030011 ms

Queue Average: 14.827731 ms

Queue Average: 12.955391 ms

Queue Average: 12.969120 ms

How can I improve my usage of the dataset pipline?

Comment: Here is a article containing many good performance tips: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/performance/datasets_performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution, we can use multi-thread in the map function:

```
tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(img_paths).map(parse_func, num_parallel_calls=num_threads)
```